# Find the directional derivative in the direction of a vector making an angle of 3π/4 with gradient vector (2,3,2)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find  the directional derivative of $ f(x,y,z) = (xy + z^2) $ at the point $(2,3,2)$ in the direction of a vector making an angle of $\theta =  3π/4 $ with gradient vector $(2,3,2)$.

The directional derivative is defined as $\nabla f(x,y,z) ⋅ u$, 
so I tried to find the vector $u$ first:

$$\cos(3π/4) = \frac{u⋅v}{||v||||u||}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{u⋅(2,3,2)}{||\sqrt17||}$$
$$-\frac{\sqrt(17)}{2} = {u⋅(2,3,2)}$$

which doesn't seem to really give me a definite vector for $u$, and I'm stuck here. Is there a way to find $u$ or am I approaching this entirely wrong?

Comment: This seems like an odd question. In $\mathbb R^3$ there exists an infinite number of vectors making a specified angle with some fixed vector, so as currently posed there is no unique correct answer.